# Ui-mask definition for alphanumeric

Tags: angularjs

I am using  `ui-mask="AA/AAA/9999999/999/9999999"` in my angularjs to read PF number
the format will be Format : `(Region Code/Office Code/Est Code/Extn No/Member Acc No) Example HR/FBD/0003256/000/0000125.`
Now, istead of Extn No 000 i need to allow alphanumeric like `000,00A,00R` for last chanracter.how to do it pls suggest.

Comment: try this `ui-mask="AA/AAA/9999999/99*/9999999"`

Comment: thanks a lot its woking fine